# Is is possible to reuse Oracle native compiled shared libraries?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Since Oracle can do a native C compilation for PL/SQL code (code is compiled with a C compiler like gcc into a shared object file on servers file system) I am wondering about this. Can I develop a piece of C code for extproc linking against the native compiled PL/SQL function? This would be a great thing, because all the difficult OCI stuff could be done in PL/SQL and all the logical or math stuff in C. Therefore I would need to know (at least, I think) the function names and parameters so that I can make a header file - right? Is there a way to reverse engineer the .so? Has anyone tried such a hack? Its more a "I want to learn and experiment" thing than solving an actual issue.

EDIT1:
What I have figured out: I can modify the $ORACLE_HOME/plsql/spnc_commands file and append a cp %(src) /tmp%(src) behind the linker command. So I can investigate the generated C code, but this is not a big help :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you looking for [OCI Oracle Call Interface](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html).